# toughness of a regular complete 3-partite graph and connectedness

Tags: graph-theory

I'v two questions relevant to toughness which is a concept i've just encountered .

How to calculate the toughness of an r-regular complete 3-partite graph with r is bigger than or equal to 2? And how to show that every 1-tough graph is 2-connected ?

Comment: I gather that there is some relationship between $1$-toughness and connectedness, but I'm unfamiliar with the definition of $k$-toughness.  Please provide a definition (or link to one) in your Question's body.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the second question. A disconnected graph has toughness $0$. Therefore $1$-tough graph is connected. Suppose it has a [cutpoint](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArticulationVertex.html). Then after deleting this $1$ vertex we get $2$ components, therefore toughness of such graph is at most $\frac12$. This contradiction shows that $1$-tough graph is $2$-connected.

For $r = 2$ complete $3$-partite $r$-regular graph is $K_3$ and has infinite toughness [by convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_toughness). Let $r \ge 4$. It is easy to see that if such graph exists then $r$ is even and each part has $\frac r2$ vertices. If after deleting some vertices graph still has two vertices from different parts then it is connected. After deliting $r$ vertices from two parts only we get $\frac r2$ isolated vertices of the third part. Therefore toughness of this graph is at most $\frac r{r/2} = 2$. Deleting more vertices gives less components, thus toughness of $r$-regular complete $3$-partite graph has toughness $2$ for even $r \ge 4$.